# Fabric.js: Using Controls not possible if objects are in group?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

It's about this small script: https://jsfiddle.net/yd0mfwen/

`
// Create a Fabric.js Canvas
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');

```
    img1 = new fabric.Circle({
        radius: 200,
        fill: 'grey',
        left: 10,
        top: 10,
        selectable: false,
    });
    canvas.add(img1);

            // transparent object to resize group to canvas size
    var base = new fabric.Rect({
        fill: 'transparent',
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        selectable: false,
        width: canvas.width,
        height: canvas.height,
    });

    var circle = new fabric.Circle({
        radius: 50,
        fill: 'red',
        left: 150,
        top: 150,
        selectable: true
    });

    var circle2 = new fabric.Circle({
        radius: 30,
        fill: 'blue',
        left: 80,
        top: 110,
        selectable: true
    });


    // Create a group to apply a mask
    var group = new fabric.Group([circle, circle2, base], {
        globalCompositeOperation: 'source-in',
        hasBorders: false,
        hasControls: false,
        selectable: false
    });

    canvas.add(group);

    group.on('mousedown', function(e) {
        var innerTarget = group._searchPossibleTargets(e.e);
        canvas.setActiveObject(innerTarget);
    });

    group._searchPossibleTargets = function(e) {
        var pointer = this.canvas.getPointer(e, true);
        var i = canvas.getObjects().length,
            normalizedPointer = this.canvas._normalizePointer(this, pointer);

        while (i--) {
            if (this.canvas._checkTarget(normalizedPointer, this._objects[i])) {
                return this._objects[i];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

`

a bit of context:
There are 3 "types" of objects: the mask, the helper and the normal ones.

mask: can be any kind of shape. in this example its an simple circle. Its placed on the canvas as first object, later added objects (grouped) will have "globalCompositeOperation: source-in", so they will only be visible "inside" the mask.

helper: a simple transparent rect with same size as the canvas. currently needed so the group of "normal" objects has the same size as the canvas (so no resize is needed when normals move).

normal: in this example 2 circles

--

normals and helper are added to one group which is then added to the canvas. And her comes the problem:
the normal objects are selectable as expected ("_searchPossibleTargets") and can be moved around, but resizing/scaling, stretching,... is not possible. The controls are visible but cannot be used via mouse.

I tried to enable the controls manually. It changed noting, since they are already enabled.

I have no explanation for this. Has someone any kind of idea? Used Version is 5.3.1